How do I reference js and css files from local library for IntroJs
I have a python 2.7 project that uses IntroJs 7. IntroJs just upgraded to a version 8 and it broke, with no warning, the functionality. I need to access 2 files from version 7, Intro.js and Introjs.css. I used to access them externally with this code on a webpage:


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/intro.js/introjs.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/intro.js/intro.js"></script>



They changed those public access files from version 7 to 8 so those links cannot be used. To deal with it I imported the provided downloadable library from IntroJs. There are many files in it, including theme css options. However the key files intro.js and introjs.css do not exist in that library. Does anyone have experience using IntroJs from a local library and, if so, how do you call the intro.js and introjs.css files if they don't exist in that library? I've downloaded the library from multiple places and those 2 files are never there.
I should add that the support for IntroJs is very vague about using the downloadable library and says nothing about calling intro.js and introjs.css locally. I've emailed them and they have been vague and unhelpful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.


version 8 is in the beta. specify a version you want to download like: https://unpkg.com/intro.js@7.2.0/intro.js

@Sysix Thanks very much for that suggestion. I hadn't thought of that--it does work, which is great. My main concern now is that it might be removed at some point in the future and I'll have the same issue. Is there a way to get/call intro.js from a local library? I've got the whole library imported to python, I just can't call it.

I would not be worried that much. Wait for the official release and then look at the upgrade guide. You are targeting now a specific version which does not change. At a "normal" js enviroment you have a package manager (mostly npm) and a bundler (vite, rollup, webpack, ...).

@Sysix Thanks for the clarification. I actually just went to the url and copied the code to a new js file in the python project, naming it 'intro.js' and referencing it locally. It seems to work normally. Do you think that's equally as reliable, or more so, than referencing the file from the link? Sorry if that's a stupid question, new process for me..

for this package in version 7 you should have no problems. Some js packages are now "module", means they are including other js files in their source code.

@Sysix got it--many thanks for your quick help!
